# How to get openEndDrawer() to respond to my custom AppBar Button instead of imaginary AppBar button?

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation-drawer, flutter-appbar

I am relatively new to flutter/dart and I want to programmatically open a drawer when a user taps on the hamburger menu on my custom appbar. However, after implementing the following code,

profile_page.dart

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
            child: CustomScrollView(
          slivers: [
            SliverAppBar(
              floating: false,
              pinned: true,
              primary: true,
              flexibleSpace: TopBar(
                title: "Profile",
                hasBackButton: false,
                hasHamburgerMenu: true,
                openDrawer: () {
                  Scaffold.of(context).openEndDrawer();
                },
              ),
              collapsedHeight: 180,
              expandedHeight: 180,
              backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(250, 250, 250, 1),
            )
          ],
        )),
        endDrawer: Drawer(
            child: ListView(
          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          children: [
            DrawerHeader(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Theme.of(context).accentColor),
                child: Text("Drawer Header")),
            ListTile(
              title: Text("Test 1"),
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
            )
          ],
        )));
  }
```

top_bar.dart

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 25.0),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
          children: [
            if (hasBackButton ?? true)
              Container(
                child: GestureDetector(
                  child: Image(
                      image: AssetImage("assets/images/previous.png"),
                      color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                      width: 25,
                      height: 25),
                  onTap: onPressed,
                ),
              )
            else
              Text(""),
            Text(""),
            Text(title ?? "Top Bar",
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 24,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
                    color: Theme.of(context).accentColor)),
            Text(""),
            if (hasHamburgerMenu ?? false)
              InkWell(
                  onTap: openDrawer, child: Icon(Icons.menu))
            else
              Text("")
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

My interface shows that the `openEndDrawer()` is tagged to an "imaginary" AppBar hamburger menu button instead of my hamburger menu icon, as seen in the below screengrab.

[image]

The hamburger menu in white that is responding to the `onTap()` is not coded in my app at all.
Glad if I could get any form of assistance on this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

End Drawer is part of the Scaffold so you can open the Drawer like this:

```dart
Scaffold.of(context).openEndDrawer();
```

Comment: I did do that in profile_page.dart .. however that is not what I asked. I can open the drawer, but the onTap() function is tagged to an "invisible" hamburger menu button instead of my appbar hamburger button. Not sure why this happens considering I did not even use the default AppBar.